# WPF DataGrid: Set ColumnWidth in a Trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datatrigger, column-width

I'm having problems to set the ColumnWidth of a DataGrid inside a trigger in his style.

I have this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
    <DataGrid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Data.Count}" Value="2">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
                    <Setter Property="ColumnWidth" Value="400" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Style>
</DataGrid>
```

In case of 2 rows I want to fill the background with green and to make wider columns, but I can't only achieve the green background.. Why the ColumnWidth setting is not working?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

It works if I put the ColumnWidth setting outside the Trigger.. but I don't want this..

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
    <DataGrid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
            <Setter Property="ColumnWidth" Value="400" />

            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Data.Count}" Value="2">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Style>
</DataGrid>
```

Thanks!

**Solved:**

Finally I have established ColumnWidt with a Binding to my data and a converter:

```
<DataGrid ColumnWidth="{Binding Data, Converter={StaticResource DataToColumnWidthConverter}}" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" IsReadOnly="True" MaxHeight="300" >
```

Converter:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(DataTable), typeof(DataGridLength))]
public class DataToColumnWidthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DataTable dt = value as DataTable;

        if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count == 2)
        {
            return new DataGridLength(400);
        }

        return new DataGridLength();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is OK for me because my data won't change number of rows in execution time, so ColumnWidth only needs to be calculated one time at beginning.

Thanks all

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove `ItemsSource` from your `DataGrid`, and move it into `DataTrigger`.
2. To set `ColumnWidth` after initial binding, re-binding is needed. You cannot set `ColumnWidth` from code, it won't have any effect. For `ColumnWidth` to have any effect, you need to first remove `DataGrid`'s `DataContext/ItemsSource` (setting to null) and then re-assign it.

So, if you change your collection somewhere, you have to first set the DataContext of DataGrid to null, and then re-assign it. See what I have done in Button click below.
 Code below is self explanatory. I have written a converter and MarkupExtension for cases when Data.Count will not be 4.

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="Dgrid" Margin="0,58,0,0">
    <DataGrid.Style>
       <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
          <Style.Triggers>
             <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Data.Count}" Value="4">
                 <Setter Property="ColumnWidth" Value="200" />
                 <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Data}" />
                 <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />                            
             </DataTrigger>
             <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Data.Count, Converter={local:CountToBool}}" Value="true">
                 <Setter Property="ColumnWidth" Value="100" />
                 <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Data}" />
                 <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
              </DataTrigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
     </DataGrid.Style>
    </DataGrid>
```

Converter :

```
    public class CountToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if ((int)value != 4)
                return true;

            return false;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class CountToBoolExtension : MarkupExtension
    {
        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return new CountToBoolConverter();
        }
    }
```

CodeBehind :

```
ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();

// removing 2 items and reassigning DataContext to viewmodel.
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Dgrid.DataContext = null;

    vm.Students.RemoveAt(1);
    vm.Students.RemoveAt(2);

    Dgrid.DataContext = vm;
}
```

Above code will change ColumnWidth depending upon the Data.Count value and works correctly if we change number of records in Collection at runtime.

Comment: Thanks! I've solved my problem in another way, but I was influenced by you solution! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

please try the next solution. As you can see I've used a proxy object to pass a main data context to each data grid cell. In addition there is a DataTrigger which works when a Visibility of a hidden column is changed and there is an attached property that helps to control the actual column width. 
Here is the code:

**Xaml Code**

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridSoHelpAttempt.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:dataGridSoHelpAttempt="clr-namespace:DataGridSoHelpAttempt"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" x:Name="This">
<Window.DataContext>
    <dataGridSoHelpAttempt:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid x:Name="MyGrid">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <dataGridSoHelpAttempt:FreezableProxyClass x:Key="ProxyElement" ProxiedDataContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference This}, Path=DataContext}"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding DataSource}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name"  Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}"  Visibility="{Binding Source={StaticResource ProxyElement}, 
                Path=ProxiedDataContext.Visibility, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Comments" Binding="{Binding Comments}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price (click to see total)" Binding="{Binding Price, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={StaticResource ProxyElement}, 
                Path=ProxiedDataContext.Visibility, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="Visible">
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="dataGridSoHelpAttempt:DataGridAttached.ColumnActualWidth" Value="200"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={StaticResource ProxyElement}, 
                Path=ProxiedDataContext.Visibility, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="Collapsed">
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="400"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="dataGridSoHelpAttempt:DataGridAttached.ColumnActualWidth" Value="400"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
    </DataGrid>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Button Content="Show Description" Command="{Binding Command}"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid></Window>
```

**Attached Property Code**

```
public class DataGridAttached
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnActualWidthProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "ColumnActualWidth", typeof (double), typeof (DataGridAttached), new PropertyMetadata(default(double), ColumnActualWidthPropertyChanged));

    private static void ColumnActualWidthPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var data = d.FindParent<DataGrid>();
        var control = (d as Control);
        if(data == null || control == null) return;
        data.Columns.ToList().ForEach(column =>
        {
            var cellWidth = control.Width;
            if(double.IsNaN(cellWidth) || double.IsInfinity(cellWidth)) return;
            column.Width = cellWidth;
        });
    }

    public static void SetColumnActualWidth(DependencyObject element, double value)
    {
        element.SetValue(ColumnActualWidthProperty, value);
    }

    public static double GetColumnActualWidth(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (double) element.GetValue(ColumnActualWidthProperty);
    }
}
```

**View Model and Model**

```
    public class MainViewModel:BaseObservableObject
{
    private Visibility _visibility;
    private ICommand _command;
    private Visibility _totalsVisibility;
    private double _totalValue;
    private double _columnWidth;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        TotalsVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        DataSource = new ObservableCollection<BaseData>(new List<BaseData>
        {
            new BaseData {Name = "Uncle Vania", Description = "A.Chekhov, play", Comments = "worth reading", Price = 25},
            new BaseData {Name = "Anna Karenine", Description = "L.Tolstoy, roman", Comments = "worth reading", Price = 35},
            new BaseData {Name = "The Master and Margarita", Description = "M.Bulgakov, novel", Comments = "worth reading", Price = 56},
        });
    }

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get
        {
            return _command ?? (_command = new RelayCommand(VisibilityChangingCommand));
        }
    }

    private void VisibilityChangingCommand()
    {
        Visibility = Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        ColumnWidth = Visibility == Visibility.Visible ? 200d : 400d;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<BaseData> DataSource { get; set; }

    public Visibility Visibility
    {
        get { return _visibility; }
        set
        {
            _visibility = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<BaseData> ColumnCollection
    {
        get { return DataSource; }
    }

    public Visibility TotalsVisibility
    {
        get { return _totalsVisibility; }
        set
        {
            _totalsVisibility = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public double TotalValue
    {
        get { return ColumnCollection.Sum(x => x.Price); }
    }

    public double ColumnWidth
    {
        get { return _columnWidth; }
        set
        {
            _columnWidth = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

public class BaseData:BaseObservableObject
{
    private string _name;
    private string _description;
    private string _comments;
    private int _price;

    public virtual string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public virtual object Description
    {
        get { return _description; }
        set
        {
            _description = (string) value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Comments
    {
        get { return _comments; }
        set
        {
            _comments = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public int Price
    {
        get { return _price; }
        set
        {
            _price = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**Freezable Helper**

```
  public class FreezableProxyClass : Freezable
{
    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new FreezableProxyClass();
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty ProxiedDataContextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ProxiedDataContext", typeof (object), typeof (FreezableProxyClass), new PropertyMetadata(default(object)));

    public object ProxiedDataContext
    {
        get { return (object) GetValue(ProxiedDataContextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ProxiedDataContextProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

**Helpers**

```
    public static class VisualTreeHelperExtensions
{
    public static T FindParent<T>(this DependencyObject child) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        while (true)
        {
            //get parent item
            DependencyObject parentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);

            //we've reached the end of the tree
            if (parentObject == null) return null;

            //check if the parent matches the type we're looking for
            T parent = parentObject as T;
            if (parent != null)
                return parent;
            child = parentObject;
        }
    }
}

public class BaseObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> raiser)
    {
        var propName = ((MemberExpression)raiser.Body).Member.Name;
        OnPropertyChanged(propName);
    }

    protected bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
        {
            field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(name);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Func<bool> _canExecute;
    private readonly Action _execute;

    public RelayCommand(Action execute)
        : this(() => true, execute)
    {
    }

    public RelayCommand(Func<bool> canExecute, Action execute)
    {
        _canExecute = canExecute;
        _execute = execute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter = null)
    {
        return _canExecute();
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter = null)
    {
        _execute();
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}

public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
    where T:class 
{
    private readonly Predicate<T> _canExecute;
    private readonly Action<T> _execute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute):this(obj => true, execute)
    {
    }

    public RelayCommand(Predicate<T> canExecute, Action<T> execute)
    {
        _canExecute = canExecute;
        _execute = execute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute(parameter as T);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter as T);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

It is complete test solution, you should take just the idea of how this is working. I'll be glad to help if you will have problems with the code.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks! I've solved my problem in another way, but I was influenced by you solution! thanks a lot!